# Weak topology on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$: Constructing neighborhoods from sequences

Tags: general-topology

I have a question concerning Example 1.8.6 in the book Algebraische Topologie by Stöcker and Zieschang.

They consider $\mathbb{R}^\infty = \lim_n \mathbb{R}^n$ as the space of sequences of real numbers $(x_n)$ where $x_k = 0$ for all $k$ greater than some $N \in \mathbb{N}$. By their definition of the weak topology, a subset $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^\infty$ is open iff all intersections $X \cap \mathbb{R}^n$ are open in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In their example, they claim that for any sequence of positive real numbers $(\varepsilon_n)$, the set $U := \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{y\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \lvert y \rvert < \varepsilon_n  \}$ is a neighborhood of $(0,\dotsc)$.

What I fail to understand: How can we find an open subset of $U$ if we take $\varepsilon_n = n^{-1}$, or more generally, any sequence that converges to 0?

Answer (score 1):

It is false. We have
$$U  = \bigcup_m B_m(\epsilon_m)$$
where $B_m(\varepsilon_m) =  \{y\in \mathbb{R}^m \mid \lvert y \rvert < \varepsilon_m  \}$ is the open ball in $\mathbb R^m$ with radius $\varepsilon_m$ and center $0$. Clearly
$$U \cap \mathbb R^n = \bigcup_m B_m(\varepsilon_m) \cap \mathbb R^n .$$
For $m \ge n$ we have $B_m(\epsilon_m) \cap \mathbb R^n = B_n(\varepsilon_m)$ which is open in $\mathbb R^n$, but for $m < n$ the set $B^n_m(\varepsilon_m) = B_m(\varepsilon_m) \cap \mathbb R^n$ is contained in the $m$-dimensional linear subspace $\mathbb R^m \subset \mathbb R^n$ and thus does not contain any interior points. Therefore, if there exists $N$ such that $\sup_{m > N}\varepsilon_m < \varepsilon_N$, then $U$ is not open in $\mathbb R^\infty$. To see this oberserve that
$$U \cap \mathbb R^{N+1} = \bigcup_{m \le N}B^{N+1}_m(\varepsilon_m) \cup \bigcup_{m > N} B_{N+1}(\varepsilon_m) .$$
The set $V = \bigcup_{m > N} B_{N+1}(\varepsilon_m)$ is the open ball with radius $\sup_{m > N}\varepsilon_m$. The set $W  = \bigcup_{m \le N}B^{N+1}_m(\varepsilon_m)$ does not contain any interior points, but due to $\sup_{m > N}\varepsilon_m < \varepsilon_N$ it contains points outside of $V$ (surely all points  $y \in B_{N+1}(\varepsilon_N)$ with $\lvert y \rvert > \sup_{m > N}\varepsilon_m$). Thus $W \cup V$ cannot be open in $\mathbb R^{N+1}$.

As an example take $\varepsilon_1 = 2, \varepsilon_m  = 1$ for $m > 1$.

**Remark:**

We have shown that in general $U$ is not an open neigborhood of $0$. But could it be that it is always a *not necessarily open* neigborhood of $0$, i.e. contains an open neigborhood of $0$? To prove that it is impossible would require much more work.

Answer (score 0):

For each $n$, $U \cap \Bbb R^n$ is essentially the open ball with radius $\varepsilon_n$ and hence open in $\Bbb R^n$. I see no issues with the convergence to $0$ at all. The definition just applies.

Comment: Maybe im missing something here, but the intersection $U\cap \mathbb{R}^2$ should be $(-\epsilon_1,\epsilon_1)\times \{0 \} \cup \{(x,y)\mid \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \epsilon_2  \}$. But this does not contain the box $(-\epsilon_1,\epsilon_1) \times (-\epsilon_2,\epsilon_2)$.

Comment: @lboeke How do you see $\Bbb R^1$ inside $\Bbb R^2$? Aren't all members of $\Bbb R^\infty$ just real sequences?

Comment: By the inclusion $x \mapsto (x,0)$. So $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is a quotient of the disjoint union of the $\mathbb{R}^n$, where the inclusions give us the equivalence relation.

Comment: @lboeke Another more convenient way to see the space is $\Bbb R^\infty = \{y=(y)_n \mid \exists N(y) \in \Bbb N: \forall n > N: y_n =0\}$ and define $\Bbb R^n = \{y \in \Bbb R^\infty: N(y)=n\}$ we give these subspaces $\Bbb R^n$ the standard topology from the norm on $\Bbb R^n$ and the open sets are as defined. Then we can even say $U \cap \Bbb R^n$is just an open ball so open by definition. So $\Bbb R^\infty$ is just an increasing union and we have an induced topology from the cover.

Comment: @lboeke I first read your $U$ as $\{(y) \in \Bbb R^\infty\mid |y_n| < \varepsilon_n\}$ instead.

Comment: Maybe the identification you suggested should have $N(y) \leq n$? Do you think the intersection with $\mathbb{R}^2$ from my first post is wrong?
l tried to show that $U$ is not a nieghbourhood for any sequence, I'll post that as a separate answer.

Comment: @lboeke no all $n > N(y)$.

Comment: @lboeke If I take $N(y)$ to be minimal then $\Bbb R^n = \{y\mid N(y) \le n\}$ yes, I think that's what you meant. So $(0,0,0,0) \in \Bbb R^1 \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise until now that you also edited the answer.
I still think that it is not correct, as the union I describe in my first comment is not contained in the ball with radius $\epsilon_2$ either for $\epsilon_1 > \epsilon_2$. So to get an open set, we would have to make the intersection with $\mathbb{R}$ smaller. But if we do this every time we go up one dimension, with the sequence from the question, then we end up with only one point.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume $V$ is an open set contained in $U$.
We then have that $V\cap \mathbb{R}^m$ is open for any $m$.
Fix some $m_1$ and find $r_{m_1}$ such that an open ball with radius $r_{m_1}$ around $0$ lies in $V\cap \mathbb{R}^{m_1}$.
Now, we look at $V\cap \mathbb{R}^{m_2}$ for some $m_2>m_1$.
This is again an open set, and therefore contains an open ball with radius $r_{m_2}$.
If now $r_{m_2} < r_{m_1}$, then the union $B^{m_1}_{r_{m_1}}(0)  \cup B^{m_2}_{r_{m_2}}(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^{m_2}$ is not open.
This means that while $V\cap \mathbb{R}^{m_2}$ contains such a union of cells, the converse is not true as long as $V$ is open.
In the case that $r_{m_2} \geq r_{m_1}$, everything is fine, but this is incompatible with a sequence like $\varepsilon_n$ in the question.

What I'm trying to get to: There should be some lower bound on the $\varepsilon_n$ in the definition of $U$.